# reduce the count by 1 after a time period of 24

Tags: matlab, time

I tried this

```
y = an integer which is updated by another code; %% (i don't find it necessary to write that code here)   

     x = 1:10; %% here i have tried to define a range  
         for i = 24*x %% tried to count at the intervals of 24, with multiples of 24
            if y < 12
             count = count - 1 ;
            end
       end
```

but it is reducing after every count. I want it to reduce after a time period of `24`. the code is written in MATLAB.  and i do not want to use the range i.e `x = 1:10`.

Comment: Is `x` your variable representing time? Do you mean `24*x` in your code?

Comment: @anu what is `y` now?

Comment: Voting to close as "Unclear" until you provide some better explanations. What is you want to do? I'm fairly certain you can skip the loop here. Can you provide some context? And yes, as Dan asks: What is `x`, `i` and `y`? What's happening inside the loop? Is `y` updated?

Comment: ok my mistake, i did not wrote the full code. i apologize for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very unclear but I will hazard a guess anyway:

```
time = 0;
while time < max_time
    if mod(time,24)==0
        count = count - 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: but what if i do not want to specify any range like (x = 1:10) can we write without describing any range

Comment: @anu how about using a `while` loop like ni my edit. But also, your question is exceptionally unclear. Please read up on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Dan please check out my edited question

Comment: @Anu your update is meaningless and adds nothing. We are not wizards or psychics. We cannot ascertain what you want if you do not explain yourself clearly. You can't talk about a *time period* if you are not going to define what that means in your code. You can't just include some variable (`y`) if you are not going to define it. Either it is important, or it does not belong in the question at all. If your entire question is how to create a range variable with increments of `24` then `x=1:24:24*10`.

Answer (score 0):

On your line

```
for i = 24x
```

that doesn't mean anything since x is a vector and you can't implicitly multiply. If you want to multiply the max value of x times 24 you can say

```
 for i = 24*x
```

Also, it makes no sense to compare x, a vector, to 12, an integer. Perhaps you're trying to call x at i, like

```
if x(i) < 12
```

But to answer your question the function for a delay is

```
pause(x)
```

So if you want count (which wasn't declared) to go down you could do something like this:

```
x = 1:10 % A vector containing values from 1 to 10
for i = 24*x % i will be 24, 48, 72, etc.
    if x(i) < 12
    count = count - 1
    pause(24)
    end
end
```

Hope that helps!